# How to interpret replacement?

Tags: perl

```
$test='abc="def"';
$replacement='$1="ghj"';
$test =~ s/(.+)="(.+)"/"$replacement/;
print $test;
```

It prints:

```
$1=ghj
```

How can I treat `$replacement` to be interpreted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are approximately 3 answers to this question.

- Your replacement "string" is actually code to be evaluated at match time to generate the replacement string. That is, it is better represented as a function:

```
my $test = 'abc="def"';
my $replacement = sub { $1 . '="ghj"' };
$test =~ s/(.+)="(.+)"/$replacement->()/e;
print $test;
```

- If you don't need the full power of arbitrary Perl expressions (or if your replacement string comes from an external source), you can also treat it as a template to be filled in with the match results. There is a module that encapsulates this in the form of a JavaScript-like `replace` function, [Data::Munge](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aMunge):

```
use Data::Munge qw(replace);
my $test = 'abc="def"';
my $replacement = '$1="ghj"';
$test = replace $test, qr/(.+)="(.+)"/, $replacement;
print $test;
```

- Finally, you can represent Perl code as a string to be [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html)'d. This is not only inefficient but also fraught with quoting issues (you have to make sure everything in $replacement is syntactically valid Perl) and security holes (if $replacement is generated at runtime, especially if it comes from an external source). My least favorite approach:

```
my $test = 'abc="def"';
my $replacement = '$1 . "=\\"ghj\\""';
$test =~ s/(.+)="(.+)"/eval $replacement/e;
print $test;
```

(The `s//eval $foo/e` part can also be written as `s//$foo/ee`. I don't like to do that because `eval` is evil and shouldn't be more hidden than it already is.)

Comment: One question.Does the ee means eval regexp and eval replacement?

Comment: The first `e` means "the right-hand side of this substitution is an expression, not a string". Every further `e` wraps another `eval(...)` around it.

Answer (score 6):

You add the `/e` modifier to your regex. You need to modify your replacement string too, so that it is evaluated correctly. Double evaluation is needed to interpolate the variable.

```
my $test='abc="def"';
my $replacement='"$1=ghj"';
$test =~ s/(.+)="(.+)"/$replacement/ee;
print $test;
```

**Output:**

```
abc=ghj
```

It should be noted that this is somewhat unsafe, especially if others can affect the value of your replacement. Then they can execute arbitrary code on your system.